# Finding the date associated with a negative value

Tags: excel, lookup

Ran into some trouble here. Would be glad if someone could help.

```
ITEMID     REFTYPE  QTY  REQDATE
128000201     1      3  
128000201     10    -1   14.08.2018
128000201     10    -1   30.08.2018
128000201     10    -2   04.09.2018
128000201     10    -1   06.09.2018
128000203     10    -2   13.08.2018
128000203     10    -1   24.08.2018
128000203     10    -1   24.08.2018
128000203     10    -1   28.08.2018
```

So I need to see each ITEMID's REQDATE when the QTY goes lower than 0.

- Substract when REFTYPE equals 1 (answer 04.09.2018).
- Case when REFTYPE does not equal 1, get the first REFTYPE's REQDATE (answer 13.08.2018).

Comment: What would the desired output look like? I get the idea of what you ask but not sure how to pack the solution.

Comment: Please consider to check out [ask] a question with a [mcve].

Comment: The desired output would be in date format, coming from REQDATE field.

Comment: Why not just use a filter?

Comment: Could you describe more of what you're thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Have found a partial solution for my problem. If anyone can assist me further on, would appreciate it. ITEMID - Column A and so on.

Currently the ROW(C2) at the end of formula is limiting ability to swap the "ITEMID" in the beginning.

```
=IF(A2:A15="128000201";INDEX(D2:D15;MATCH(0;SUBTOTAL(9;OFFSET(C2;;;ROW(C2:C15)-ROW(C2)));-1)))
```